# Trigger ids on click and when a specific id reaches top of window

Tags: parallax

I am trying to build a parallax based page. I have the elements moving based on when a user clicks on links, but I want other animation to trigger when the div reaches TOP not only on click function. How can I get #circ1, #circ2, #circ3 and #circ4 begin animation on click and also when #english-channel reaches the

```
$('a.english-channel').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop:$('#english-channel').offset().top
    }, 1000, function() {
        parallaxScroll(); // Callback is required for iOS
    });
        $(function(){
            $('#circ1').delay(1200).animate({
            width: '150px',
            height: '150px',
            opacity: '1.0'
            },500);
            $('#circ2').delay(1400).animate({
            width: '300px',
            height: '300px',
            opacity: '1.0'
            },400);
            $('#circ3').delay(1600).animate({
            width: '750px',
            height: '750px',
            opacity: '1.0'
            },300);
            $('#circ4').delay(1800).animate({
            width: '1350px',
            height: '923px',
            opacity: '1.0'
            },200);
        });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use waypoint.js in your project to trace the elements in your web page.
so that whenever they come in to the window it just triggers some action

for example you want #circ1 to be animated you should do this in this way

```
    $("#circ1").waypoint(function(event, direction) {
            $('#circ1').delay(1200).animate({
            width: '150px',
            height: '150px',
            opacity: '1.0'
            },500);
    });
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You are better of using a JavaScript library such as Skrollr.js.

You will have a better control of your animations and the timing.

Here are a few tutorials to help you get started:

- [Simple parallax scrolling tutorial](http://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/)
- [How to create a parallax scrolling website](http://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/)